# Angle between two rays given, to find a curve with constant sum of intersection angles

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

Two given lines $AB, AC$ including  $\angle A= 60^{\circ}$ between them are intersected by a variable  smooth continuous curve (red) so that angle sum $ \beta+\gamma = 150^{\circ} $ is always constant.

> How do we find such a curve, assuming it exists?

If instead the angle sum is $ \beta+\gamma = 120^{\circ} $ then we have all moving transversal straight lines. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand: the two intersection points appear to be arbitrary (so long as one is on $AB$ and the other on $AC$) and one of the angles seems to be arbitrary (with the other being $150^\circ$ minus that angle), and you then can place an  arbitrary  smooth continuous curve between them.  Is there something else I have missed,  such as the curve remaining the same and meeting these constraints even if two or three of $A$ or $B$ or $C$ are changed?

Comment: $\angle A,AB,AC $ are fixed. Intersection points are variable, so they are not labelled. The curve need not be same by translation or rotation but its equation should have a standard form ( either analytical or differential ) and if known, a name like for example the straight line for the simpler case.